# How to export/import sequence of Mariadb 10.3

Tags: mariadb

From version 10.3, Mariadb introduces sequence object(not the storage engine).

XtraBackup did backup seq object as table, and when restored, it can't be used as seq anymore.

How can I show all seq in the database, and export all seq object to a sql file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sequence-overview/#notes):

> One of the goals with the Sequence implementation is that all old tools, such as mysqldump, should work unchanged, while still keeping the normal usage of sequence standard compatibly.

So you can use `mysqldump` to dump it as a table, and then import it again with e.g. the `mysql` command-line client, and it will be turned into a sequence yet again. You can also use `SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type='SEQUENCE';` to display a list of sequences.

I would also think that `mariabackup`, which is MariaDB's fork of Percona's XtraBackup, will backup sequences correctly.

Comment: "SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type='SEQUENCE';  " works.

Comment: @RocKing You're right. I've updated to say `SHOW FULL ...`